# maven eclipse:eclipse target generates bad .classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath, multi-module

I have a maven parent project P with two child modules A and B. Both A and B are inside the P folder. P has a modules section in the *pom.xml* resembling:

```
<modules>
  <module>A</module>
  <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

A has (and B the same except the artifact):

```
<parent>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Now I made A depend on B by adding to A's *pom.xml*:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I do a `mvn install` on P, then all is fine. However after running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on P, the generated *.classpath* file in A is incorrect, and Eclipse can't resolve the dependencies from B.

The generated *.classpath* includes:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/B"/>
```

instead of the working

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/some/group/B/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/B-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
```

What could be wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the property useProjectReferences to false (with -DuseProjectReferences=false), then it should work like you want (default is true). See the docs [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html)

Comment: Thank you. This is a workaround as it turns out - the root of the problem is that I have A and B under the P directory, while the eclipse:eclipse target generates the reference as /B instead of /P/B. Maybe I'll need to switch to a flat project structure.

Comment: Note: researching more on the issue, flat structure is less preferred. So we can stick with either artifact references and mvn install, or maybe using the parent project as a workspace and directly importing the children. Or someone could fix the .classpath generation to correctly include the child path relative to the workspace.